# SSD not being detected by ubuntu linux 14.04 or mountain lion machines

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, hard-drive, data-recovery, ssd

My question is as the title suggests. I have extremely important data in my samsung evo SSD that was in my macbook, and I got too overconfident while doing some repairs and didn't back it up..:(

So what happened was - I was about to remove the SSD from the mac (the screen was open) and I pressed the power button. The login screen came immediately :(. I was already in the flow of pulling it out, and I did. Now I fear the SSD might be dead, or more hopefully the partitioning table has got slightly messed up.

I bought a hard drive enclosure and put the SSD in it. I hooked the enclosure up to my ubuntu machine...and it didn't seem to recognize it. The output of sudo fdisk -l is as follows-

```
Disk /dev/sda: 120.0 GB, 120034123776 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 14593 cylinders, total 234441648 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00059aa7

Device Boot Start End Blocks Id System
/dev/sda1 * 2048 499711 248832 83 Linux
/dev/sda2 501758 234440703 116969473 5 Extended
/dev/sda5 501760 234440703 116969472 8e Linux LVM

Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: 117.6 GB, 117633449984 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 14301 cylinders, total 229752832 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1: 2139 MB, 2139095040 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 260 cylinders, total 4177920 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000
```

As you can tell, it didn't detect it. I'm pretty sure it's format is HFS+. So I hooked it up to a mac running, Mountain Lion and it couldn't detect it in the finder, or in disk utility.

This is seriously freaking me out guys. Is there any data recovery tool you guys would recommend? Please help me. As I have some technical knowledge, I'm not scared of using a terminal or anything. And I read something about partition recovery. Can that help?

Hopefully this can get solved quick :)

Comment: Make sure you didn't forget to connect the *power* plug? ;)

Comment: It looks like the Ubuntu system isn't detecting the *physical disk* (I'd expect it to be `/dev/sdb`). This is *not* (simply) a data structure (partition table, filesystem, etc.) problem, but a problem with the *hardware.* Given that you've added new hardware in the form of the enclosure, I'd begin by focusing on that. Are all the cables snug? Is it powered on? Does the enclosure work with another disk? You could also try plugging the SSD back into your Mac and use an Ubuntu installer in "try before installing" mode to see if you can work on the disk in its original environment.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the enclosure is alright because I tried with an external sata to usb converter and a hard-drive enclosure. Both didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

1. Look at the output of `dmesg` to see what the device name is when you plug in the SSD/when you boot.
2. `blkid` will list all the block devices the kernel can see and tell you about what is on them (filesystem, partition table, label). Look for the device name from step one in the output.
3. Try to mount the block device (the one with a filesystem from `blkid`). See the `mount` command for details. If you get an error, check `dmesg` for details.

Comment: Does dmesg list disks connected in the past?

Comment: Only for the current boot session.

For 16.04 and later systemd collects kernel messages (which is what dmesg is showing you), so you can look at `journalctl -k` for the same effect (only the current boot). `jounalctl -k -b-0` shows the previous boot, `journalctl -k -b-1` for the one before that etc.

For versions prior to 16.04 look in /var/log for kern.log files (which may be rotated ie compressed).

Comment: I doesn't seem like it is detecting it..I think I need to go to a data recovery center

Comment: Can whoever downvoted my answer explain why it is not correct/appropriate? If it is because the drive is broken, I don't think it makes my answer any less valid...

Comment: If you have another device compatible with that interface, plug it in to verify the controller isn't fried, and as a corollary plug the questionable device in somewhere else to see if it is detected there...